How should we understand the term “Godhead” in contrast to “the fullness of Godhead bodily” and in relation to God?
Romans 1:20:- For since the creation of the world His invisible attributes are clearly seen, being understood by the things that are made, even His eternal power and Godhead, so that they are without excuse, …
Colossians 2:9:- For in Him dwells all the fullness of the Godhead bodily; …

The New Testament has three distinct words used to convey the concept of God's nature:

θεῖος used in Acts 17:29, 2 Peter 1:3, 4; also in LXX-Proverbs 2:17.
θειότης used in Romans 1:20. Not in the LXX.
θεότης used in Colossians 2:9. Not in the LXX.

θεῖος
Acts 17:29 (DRA)

Being therefore the offspring of God, we must not suppose the divinity to be like unto gold, or silver, or stone, the graving of art, and device of man.

2 Peter

3 As all things of his divine power which appertain to life and godliness, are given us, through the knowledge of him who hath called us by his own proper glory and virtue. 4 By whom he hath given us most great and precious promises: that by these you may be made partakers of the divine nature: flying the corruption of that concupiscence which is in the world.

Proverbs 2:17 (LXX-NETS)

My son, do not let bad counsel overtake you, that which forsakes the teaching of your youth and has forgotten the divine covenant.

Each use is in conjunction with the concept of children, and children of God.
θειότης
Romans 1:20 (ESV)

For the invisible things of him, from the creation of the world, are clearly seen, being understood by the things that are made; his eternal power also, and divinity: so that they are inexcusable.

This use is in conjunction with the created world
θεότης
Colossians 2

8 Beware lest any man cheat you by philosophy, and vain deceit; according to the tradition of men, according to the elements of the world, and not according to Christ: 9 For in him dwelleth all the fulness of the Godhead corporeally; 10 And you are filled in him, who is the head of all principality and power:

This use is about Christ.
Discussion
There are three distinct words used to convey the concept of divinity. In the New Testament one word is used three times; the other two are used once.
θεῖος is used most and is the only one used in the LXX. The sense of these uses can be seen as coming under the principle mankind was created in the image of God. θειότης is used just once. It too can be seen as speaking of creation. The difference between θειότης and θεῖος is θειότης is limited to the natural world and in doing so makes a distinction between things and mankind.
This distinction follows the complete argument Paul makes:

18 For the wrath of God is revealed from heaven against all ungodliness and injustice of those men that detain the truth of God in injustice: 19 Because that which is known of God is manifest in them. For God hath manifested it unto them. 20 For the invisible things of him, from the creation of the world, are clearly seen, being understood by the things that are made; his eternal power also, and divinity: so that they are inexcusable. 21 Because that, when they knew God, they have not glorified him as God, or given thanks; but became vain in their thoughts, and their foolish heart was darkened. 22 For professing themselves to be wise, they became fools. 23 And they changed the glory of the incorruptible God into the likeness of the image of a corruptible man, and of birds, and of fourfooted beasts, and of creeping things.

Man, created in the image of God should understand θεῖος. Man should not use things which purport to show the nature of God, θειότης. The sense of both θειότης and θεῖος is to refer to the nature of God perceived through creation, θειότης refers to things and θεῖος refers to mankind.
Lastly, Paul prefaces θεότης by exluding elements of the world. This reinforces the uniqueness by stating θεότης contrasts to the nature perceived from the natural world. In terms of Pauline doctrine, those who believe in the resurrection of Jesus and call Him Lord, are a new creation. Believers have θεότης in them. That is, before Christ mankind being made in the image of God could perceive θεῖος. Those who are in Christ know θεότης, the nature of God in them.
Conclusion
In Romans Paul states the nature of the God may be understood from things created. This understanding is more limited than what is described in Colossians, yet is sufficient so that man should seek God not make idols.
Those who believe in the resurrection and make Jesus Lord, have a greater knowledge of God's nature: it is in them. One could summarize the difference as personal knowledge from experience compared to objective knowledge by examining nature. The person before Christ had θεῖος and could understand θειότης; the person with Christ now understands θεότης.

These verses involve two different words whose meaning is given by BDAG as follows:

θειότης (theiotés) (of a divinity; the term in such a description is not tautologous but usually refers to performance that one might
properly associate with a divinity ...) the quality or
characteristic(s) pertaining to deity, divinity, divine nature,
divineness, Rom 1:20


θεότης (theotés) the state of being god, divine character/nature, deity, divinity, used as abstract noun for
theos, Col 2:9

The former is about God and the latter is about Jesus.
HELPS Word-studies gives this:

theótēs (a feminine noun derived from 2316 /theós, "God") – the
personal God revealed in the Bible who is triune and infinitely
relational as demonstrated by the embodiment of the Godhead in the
incarnated Christ (used only in Col 2:9).
theótēs ("fullness of deity") expresses God's "essential (personal)
deity, as belonging to Christ" (WS, 906). theótēs focuses on Christ
physically embodying the Godhead through His incarnation and shown
throughout His perfect life of faith (cf. Heb 12:2).


I'm all for the use of a lexicon, such as BDAG, in order to be able to see the full range of meaning, but HELPS, at least when it comes to defining scripture, seemingly leaves a lot to be desired. As far as the two scriptures in question are concerned I see an obvious bias towards "Trinitarian" influence, which could be said to be ... bordering on hermeneutical fallacy:-"illegitimate totality transfer" ... as one theologian of note puts it. He goes on to say:- Why should one try and reinvent the wheel, when one has a tried and true lexicon.

In addition to the excellent answers already provided, here are some more items that might be of some interest.
The archaic suffix of the (circa 1200 CE middle English) term, Godhead, obscures the contrast and nuances between the words, God (as a being), divinity (as an attribute), and Deity (as position or in relationship).  It often helps to look at such words in context and in literal Greek.

The for invisible qualities of Him from [the] creation of [the] world
by the things made being understood are clearly seen the both eternal
of Him power and divinity (theiotēs) for to be them without
excuse. – Romans 1:20 https://biblehub.com/interlinear/romans/1.htm


For in Him dwells all the fullness of the Diety (Theotētos)
bodily. – Colossians 2:9 https://biblehub.com/interlinear/colossians/2.htm

Archaic words and in this case, suffixes, don’t help our understanding of the intent of the text. The suffix, -head is used only in Godhead and maidenhead. What does the -hood in neighborhood mean or the -ship in fellowship and relationship?

In Romans 1:20, "Godhead' is in reference to the divine authority of God, being God the Father,  God the Son, and God the Holy Spirit.
Genesis 1:26

And God said, Let us make man in our image, after our likeness: and let them have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over the cattle, and over all the earth, and over every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth. (my emphasis)

Acts 2:23

Him, being delivered by the determinate counsel and foreknowledge of God, ye have taken, and by wicked hands have crucified and slain: (my emphasis)

In Colossians 2:9, "Godhead bodily" refers to Christ (from verse 8), being God the Son (in the flesh), filled with God the Father, and God the Holy Spirit.
2 Corinthians 5:19

To wit, that God was in Christ, reconciling the world unto himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed unto us the word of reconciliation. (my emphasis)

Luke 4:1

And Jesus being full of the Holy Ghost returned from Jordan, and was led by the Spirit into the wilderness, (my emphasis)

